# How to find if two person following each other

Tags: mysql

This is my table `following` now i want to find the list of follower of user 1 that are also followed by user 1

```
id   | user  |  follower
-----------------------
 1 |    1        | 2
 2 |    2        | 1
 3 |    1        | 3
 4 |    3        | 1
```

For example i want to find the list of my followers who are also following me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With [EXISTS](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html):

```
select t.follower from tablename t
where 
  t.user = 1
  and exists (
    select 1 from tablename 
    where user = t.follower and follower = t.user
  )
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/ww1reXYWgoAtcp5sTeW3ni/0).
Results

```
| follower |
| -------- |
| 2        |
| 3        |
```

Comment: why have you used select 1

Comment: select 1 could be select 0 or select *, this 1 has not any special meaning, as long as the subquery returns a row. You can change it to `select *` it will not make any difference

Comment: See the demo and check if there are any differences in the table structure that you did not mention.

Answer (score 0):

You could self-join the table:

```
SELECT f1.user
FROM   followers f1
JOIN   followers f2 ON f1.user = f2.follower AND f1.follower = f2.user
WHERE  f1.follower = 1 -- For a specific user
```

Comment: @nitin care to elaborate?